# Raycast to boundingBox of TextGeometry rather than the mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm trying to raycast to TextGeometry's boundingBox. Currently, raycasting works for textGeometry when click is on the letters not around or inbetween letters. If the click is inbetween the text letters/aphabets, no object is intersected with intersectObjects(). I need the raycast to intersect the textGeo object when click is inbetween the letters as well.

I'm defining TextGeometry as:

```
var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {
                    size: size,
                    height: 1,
                    font: 'helvetica'
                });

textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: fontColor });
var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);
```

After searching for solutions, going with the boundingBox seemed the best approach. Please advice or point to how this can be achieved. Any ideas or tips on how to do this? Or if there is any currently available approach.

How would I make the raycast intersect the bounding box?

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution in the Three.js lib itself. They have an optimization piece in the raycast function for a Mesh that looks at the BoundingBox and BoundingSphere to figure if the ray falls outside to skip checking for intersection. I flipped it around for my case:

```
var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4(), ray = new THREE.Ray();
//for example textGeo is the textGeometry
inverseMatrix.getInverse(textGeo.matrixWorld);
ray.copy(raycaster.ray).applyMatrix4(inverseMatrix);

if(textGeo.geometry.boundingBox !== null){
    if(ray.isIntersectionBox(textGeo.geometry.boundingBox) === true){
       //intersected
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution to a problem I'm trying to solve. Would you be able to give a fuller example of its use? Or point to somewhere where this is in use? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the bounding box of your geometry and create geometry for the bbox.
2. Create a `THREE.Object3D` and add the bounding as its child (name it obbox)
3. Add obbox to the scene.

Now if you intersect the scene you will get the obbox object first because it will always be closer to the origin of the ray.

Comment: This is something I've thought about but was looking for a different approach. As I'm creating many Textgeos, wanted to avoid the overhead of having a duplicate object for each of them. Looking for a solution that can work with the existing geometry rather than having to create a new one for each.

Comment: you will not be creating a duplicate object but a much lower level of detail object ideal for raycasting. so it is actually a win-win situation because you will not need to raycast against the geometry of textgeos (which can become quite large). You will only have to raycast against the six faces of a parallelogram.

Comment: I like your approach too but for the scenario I wanted to do, I found the approach above works better. Thanks for your answer and comments, much appreciated.